# Stata function or code for correcting observations already captured

Tags: stata

I have individual file in stata with unique ID caseid. I have variables showing whether the first child was a twin the second child was a twin (b1..b2)

but instead of having that I am interested in having  avariable b1(first child) as first multiple... variable b2 second multiple since they are twins like. How can I do it in stata looping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Does all your sample of families have two children?

Let's suppose your data is: id twin1 twin2

```
*Example:
clear
set obs 10
gen id = _n
gen byte twin1 = 0
gen byte twin2 = 0
replace twin1 = 1 if inlist(id,3,8,9)
replace twin2 = 1 if inlist(id,1,4,5,7)
```

You could reshape the data into a long format:

```
reshape long twin, i(id) j(birth)
```

Then create an indicator if first_child:

```
gen byte first_child = 0
replace first_child = 1 if birth == 1
```

Then multiply the two if you wish:

```
gen first_child_twin = first_child*twin
```